# All combination of chars in a specific way with C#

Tags: c#

I have a charset of `A-Z0-9` and I search for a solution how to get all combinations - but I have some requirements:

- I have to generate all combinations with a length of 1 to 9 (later maybe 1 to 15).
- The order should be "A, AA, AAA, AAAA...., AAAAAAAAA" and after that "AAAAAAAAB".
- It should be breakable: I have to send every item against an API.
  For example: if the item does not respond to "AAAA" I can ignore all other item that starts with "AAAA"; I can skip to "AAAB"

I think it is not resolveable with a simple permutation algorithm, but I'm sure there is an algorithm existing (but I dont know the name of it).

Comment: Effectively, this is a pruned tree with a 36x branching factor.  It could get very big, but once a node is terminal (the "AAAA" in your example) it no longer contributes to the branching factor.  You can use a recursive algo that returns once no response is received.

Comment: Describe in details how the symbols should follow. Limit yourself to three symbols. After AAA comes AAB and then? AAC or ABA or what? Why doesn't B come after A?